# Should general entity classes be put under service or api module in Liferay 7.4?

Tags: web-services, liferay-7, liferay-service-builder

I have a general entity class `ProductFilter`, which encloses the input parameters of a JSONWS POST end point. After building services, where should I put this class, under module `api` or module `service`?

First I put it under `service`, then an interface in `api` complained `ProductFilter` could not be found.

```
C:\Users\Zirui\projects\nongzi\code\nongzi-gradle2\modules\db\db-api\src\main\java\com\toptoken\core\service\ProductService.java:26: error: package com.toptoken.core.domain.page does not exist
import com.toptoken.core.domain.page.ProductFilter;
                                    ^
```

Then I put it under `api`, but deployment of `service` threw an exception that `service` could not find `ProductFilter` although `service` depends on `api`.

> 2023-08-22 08:13:26.489 ERROR [fileinstall-directory-watcher][DirectoryWatcher:1173] Unable to start bundle: file:/C:/Users/Zirui/projects/web3/test/gradle-wsdd/bundles/osgi/modules/com.toptoken.core.service-1.0.0.jar
> com.liferay.portal.kernel.log.LogSanitizerException: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.toptoken.core.service [1627]_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.toptoken.core.domain.page_ [Sanitized]

Then finally I put `ProductFilter` under both `api` and `service`, but deployment gave an error:

> java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @5c03e79e (instance of org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader, child of com.liferay.shielded.container.internal.ShieldedContainerClassLoader @3fc9dfc5 com.liferay.shielded.container.internal.ShieldedContainerClassLoader) wants to load class com.toptoken.core.domain.page.ProductFilter. **A different class with the same name was previously loaded by org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @38c9a210** (instance of org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader, child of com.liferay.shielded.container.internal.ShieldedContainerClassLoader @3fc9dfc5 com.liferay.shielded.container.internal.ShieldedContainerClassLoader).

Under which module, `api` or `service`, should I put `ProductFilter`?

Answer (score 0):

As the request body of a POST endpoint, I have to use `HashMap<String, Object>`. No more general entity classes.